# Plot vertical lines at a certain time

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to plot a line at a certain "x" (being a scalar) value so every second, a vertical line with certain values will be drawn. I know that one way to plot a vertical line (without considering time) is to declare a vector like:

```
y=0:0.01:5;
```

or something like:

```
y=3:0.01:6;
```

and write `plot(x,y);`

Also, I've done "animated" plots using the "pause" parameter but I don't know how to do that in this case. Thanks for your help.

Comment: what is 'x'? How can I copy past ur example to see it working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way I can suggest is to use `plot` in combination with `hold on`.  With `plot`, you'd only specify two points where each point has the same `x` value, but the `y` value can change to whatever you want.  When you draw points using `plot`, the default behaviour is that a line is drawn in between the points.  If we specify two points having the same `x` coordinate, but different `y` coordinates, we would essentially draw a vertical line in between these points.

For example, given that you want to have every "second" have a vertical line, we can do something like this:

```
ystart = [-1 -2 -3 -1 -2 -3];
yend = [1 2 3 1 2 3];

figure; hold on;
for idx = 1 : numel(ystart)
    plot([idx idx], [ystart(idx) yend(idx)]);
end
```

This is what we get:

[image]

We define two arrays of 6 elements where `ystart` denote the starting `y` point and `yend` denote the ending `y` point.  We spawn a new figure, use `hold on` to plot multiple lines on the same graph, then use a `for` loop with `plot` so that we draw a line in between two points: `(x,y) = (idx, ystart(idx))` and `(x,y) = (idx, yend(idx))`.  `idx` goes from 1 to 6.  Obviously, you can change the location of where the `x` values are being plotted by specifying another array... call it `x`:

```
x = 0:2:10; %// Time values
ystart = [-1 -2 -3 -1 -2 -3];
yend = [1 2 3 1 2 3];

figure; hold on;
for idx = 1 : numel(ystart)
    plot([x(idx) x(idx)], [ystart(idx) yend(idx)]);
end
```

Here, we will draw vertical lines starting from `x = 0` up to `x = 10` in steps of 2.  The result would basically be the same, but the `x` values would be different, as well as where the vertical lines are being drawn.

Comment: Sure let me know. If it works, I wouldn't mind you accepting my answer. Good luck!

Comment: adding in the for cycle the line "pause(1)" made it work as I wanted. Thanks, and sure I'll do.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to plot vertical lines in Matlab. The easiest recommendation is the `line` function:

> line(X,Y) adds the line defined in vectors X and Y to the current
>   axes. If X and Y are matrices of the same size, line draws one line
>   per column.

Call this as many times as you want.

```
  h=line(X,Y)
```

will give you properties of the line

Another way is to

```
X= X0*(Y./Y)
```

then

```
plot(X,Y)
```

will plot a vertical line at the point X0. Another thing you can do is draw a line using the above `line` function from the point `(X0, min(Y))` to the point `(X0, max(Y))` which is the most elegant solution. If you are trying to create a movie, you will need to access the properties of this line using `h=line(X,Y)`. To move the line to a new position, you will have to set the properties of this line by calling `set(h, Property, value)`. For example in your movie, you need to move it to a new position so you will set that property. This way, by minimum change of data, you can move a line or show its accelerating.